# Contract assembly included in executable is not found

Tags: c#, mef, .net-assembly, contract

I'm using MEF to develop a plugin system. The basic plugins are merged (using `ilmerge`) with the executable to get one single executable. These plugins are loaded using the `AssemblyCatalog`. But it should be possible to add plugins using the `DirectoryCatalog`, too.

My Class library project references the contract library and exports a class using MEF. When the executable tries to load the dll it claims that it cannot resolve the dependency to the contract library - which is included in the exe. It works if I copy the Contract.dll to the same directory. But it is included in the exe anyway?

How can I avoid copying the Contract?

Comment: Have you added reference on System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll ?

Comment: Can you publish your code : Contract + Host with your agregator + consummer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code to ensure that you expose your library in your host

```
AssemblyCatalog assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
DirectoryCatalog directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"...");//Replace with your path

AggregateCatalog catalog =
    new AggregateCatalog(new ComposablePartCatalog[] { assemblyCatalog, directoryCatalog  }); 

CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing.